# A way to directly open 'Cleanup recommendation' settings GUI, from Command prompt (or) powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, settings, command-prompt, windows-11

Is there any way to directly open 'Cleanup recommendation' settings GUI, from Command prompt (or) powershell.
[image]

**Start-Process "explorer.exe" "ms-settings:storagesense"** --> this powershell command is opening System>storage page.
similarly is it possible to open System>Storage>Cleanup recommendations page?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

`Start-Process "explorer.exe" "ms-settings:storagerecommendations"`

Comment: Thanks you for responding, 
 
The command Start-Process "explorer.exe" "ms-settings:storagerecommendations" is behaving differently depending on the state of the Settings app:

First run: It opens the Storage page (System > Storage).
Second run (Storage page already open): It takes you directly to the Cleanup recommendations section (System > Storage > Cleanup recommendations).

Are you facing the same scenario?

Comment: Pretty cool, I didn't notice that before. I've tested a little, and depending on what you need it for, you could do this, this worked for me but might not fit your needs ` Start-Process "explorer.exe" "ms-settings:storagerecommendations" && Start-Sleep -s 10 && Start-Process "explorer.exe" "ms-settings:storagerecommendations"`

Comment: 'Cleanup recommendations' option is not getting enabled immediately. It is taking 2-3 seconds for getting enabled, maybe this can be the reason.